# Making a long macro/shortcut in Latex

Tags: macros, floats, preamble

I was wondering if it was possible to make a big macro, for inserting figures?
I wanted it to contain:

```
\begin{figure} [H]

\centering

\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{#FILENAME}

\caption{#FIGURECAPTION \label{#LABELREF}}

\end{figure}
```

Seeing it being so long, I wanted to make it easier to insert such a long "code". 
Should I make it as an environment in the preamble? Or as a new command?

I would be grateful for any kind of help I could get!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! You can highlight code in your post using back-ticks. For code-blocks indent them by four spaces or use the `{}` on the gui. It is better to post a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that starts with a `\documentclass` command, has a minimal preamble and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. Unless the problem is a compilation error, the code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to help you --- and much ore likely that they will!

Comment: You certainly can, but you lose in markup.

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried:

```
\newcommand\Figure[3]{%
  \begin{figure} [H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{#1}
    \caption{#2}\label{#3}
  \end{figure}
}
```

You would use this as

```
\Figure{filename}{caption}{label}
```

Actually, even better would be:

```
\newcommand\Figure[4][scale=0.8]{%
  \begin{figure} [H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[#1]{#2}
    \caption{#3}\label{#4}
  \end{figure}
}
```

The second variant defines an optional argument, which defaults to `scale=0.8`, for passing arguments to `\includegraphics`. For example, you could write things like `\Figure[width=3cm]{filename}{caption}{label}`.

**Edit: optional short caption**

Sigur asked in the comments for an optional short caption. This is actually slightly trickier in the sense that the following does not work:

```
\newcommand\Figure[4][]{%
  \begin{figure} [H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{#2}
    \caption[#1]{#3}\label{#4}
  \end{figure}
}
```

because with no optional argument `#1` is blank and the macro inserts `\caption[]{...long caption...}`, so the short caption is empty! To get around this you could instead make the default value of `#1` equal to `\relax`, for example, and then in the macro use

```
\ifx#1\relax\relax\caption{#3}\else\caption[#1]{#3}\fi
```

Now the macro behaves as expected.

A better solution, however, is to use `\NewDocumentCommand` from the [xparse](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xparse) package because this will allow you to have two optional arguments. Here is one way of doing it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{float}
\NewDocumentCommand\Figure{o D<>{scale=0.8} m m m}{%
  % [optional short caption]<optional includegraphics options>{image}{caption}{label}
  \begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[#2]{#3}
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}{\caption{#4}}{\caption[#1]{#4}}
    \label{#5}
  \end{figure}
}
\begin{document}

  \Figure{example-image-a}{Normal figure}{f:normal}

  \Figure<width=20mm>{example-image-a}{Width 20mm }{f:20mm}

  \Figure[Short caption]<width=20mm>{example-image-a}{With 20mm with short caption}{f:20mm}

  \Figure[Short caption]{example-image-a}{Short caption}{f:20mm}

\end{document}
```

An optional argument in between `[...]` will become the short-caption and an optional argument in between `<...>` will be given to `\includegraphics`, with the default being `scale=0.8`.

Comment: Well, what about another optional argument for short caption?

Comment: @Sigur I have edited the solution to do this.